# How to calculate the reliability of PUF instance?

Tags: reliability

I have an Arbiter PUF with reliability of 99.58%. Suppose I have 256 input to the PUF which generates 256 responses as an output. Now, I want to replace the 50% of input bits with 50% of response bits, randomly. In fact, I create a feedback loop between the output and input of the Arbiter PUF. My question is that what is the reliability of my new PUF instance?

I believe that the reliability of the new PUF may be less than 99.58%, because the error may get propagated from the output to the input of PUF

Comment: Sorry, I need a little clarification. After the feedback loop gets created, both real input and real output are reduced to 128 bits, right? And the 50% output bits are used for the next call of the PUF along with the next real input?